# MacOS Ventura-Apple Mail: How to search text string in message body

Tags: mail.app, email, search

On 24 Feb 2021, user Aivar Paalberg answered a similar question: <<I agree that this is cryptic. But by default it do search whole message. And it works also following way: write into search field from:apple, then select from appearing drop-down menu with arrow movement Sender contains Apple. This will make display of search box as on screenshot above. Now enter search keyword(s) for message body after that and search will be performed on mail content. This delivers search result of mails sent by Apple which have keyword in mail content (there is also has attachment search option if you are looking for invoice). – Aivar Paalberg Feb 24, 2021 at 20:57>>

I do not understand his direction about the "arrow movement" to be given the option for "Sender contains Apple." Maybe that worked in the OS version at the time, but I can't make any amount of arrow movement do anything. The only options I'm given in the drop down are to search for sender, subject, or attachment.

Has any progress been made in Apple Mail to provide this very common search task?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using a gmail account.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original question?

Comment: Link to [original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414391/searching-for-emails-containing-specified-text-string-in-body-of-email-messages). And it works in Ventura as described. However, dropdown menu is context dependent and easier is to search from body of email message `message:search_term` and press enter

Comment: My situation is I don't know which message the desired text string is in. I believe I know who the sender was and that's what I'm trying to confirm but there are a lot of messages from this person and I don't know the date it was sent, either.